# Custom UI XML Error on only one computer?

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database that throws errors upon logging in....but only on one person's computer.  No one else in the same firm has the issue.

It gives him the error: Custom UI Runtime Error in FileName.accdb  (of course I didn't put the -real- filename).

The error code is 0x80004005, and the message is "Controls in a built-in group cannot be modified".

The problem here is that only one person has this occurring, and no one else.  Could this be a permissions issue?